# Spring Boot HQL query where clause on two joins to one table

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have problem building my HQL Query in Spring Boot.
There are equal questions, but in HQL I found no matching answere which made it clear to me.

Examplary State:

```
class Reservations{
 ...
 @ManyToMany 
 List<Day> avaDays;
 @ManyToMany
 List<Day> blockedDays;
}

class Day{
 ...
 Date date;
}
```

Now I want to find all Reservations which are available and NOT blocked.
End up here:

```
@Query("
SELECT r.id, d.date 
FROM Reservation r, Day d
LEFT OUTER JOIN r.blockedDays
LEFT JOIN r.avaDays
WHERE d.date = 1506297600000"
```

... and get no results. Is the query OK? Or what did I miss?

One step further...

```
@Query("
SELECT r.id, d.date 
FROM Reservation r
LEFT OUTER JOIN r.blockedDays bd
LEFT OUTER JOIN r.avaDays ad
LEFT OUTER JOIN "furtherfilter" 
WHERE ad.date = 1506297600000 AND bd.date != 1506297600000"
```

And it works. Until I add "further filter" on that query which creates rows which dont have an blockedDays entry... and shows that rows anyway.

Guess I need to take another look on the JOINs now?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT r.id FROM Reservation r
WHERE d.avaDays.date = 1506297600000 and r.blockedDays.date != 1506297600000
```

but I do feel your architecture might need changing where in you should only need `blockedDays`. If you can elaborate more on your requirements I might be able to help.

Comment: About the architecture you are right. I am not happy with that too. But its a combination of saved DATEs and saved DAYS (monday, tuesday ... etc).
And therefore save exceptions DATES for the saved DAYS. ... open for suggestions :-)

Comment: The solutions throws an exception:
`Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [reserv0_.id.availableDates] with element property reference [date] [SELECT...`

Comment: for that you would need to close this question by accepting the answer and ask a fresh one with your detailed requirements as that will be better

Comment: is there a field availableDates ?

Comment: sure. In real code the avaDays are availableDates. 
And yes, If I come to that point I ll open an Question for this.

Comment: then replace avaDays by availableDates

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("
SELECT r.id, d.date 
FROM Reservation r
LEFT OUTER JOIN r.blockedDays bd
LEFT OUTER JOIN r.avaDays ad
LEFT OUTER JOIN "furtherfilter" 
WHERE ad.date = 1506297600000 AND bd.date != 1506297600000"
```

And it works. Until I add "further filter" on that query which creates rows which dont have an blockedDays entry... and shows that rows anyway.
Guess I need to take another look on the JOINs now.?

EDIT2: "solution"

The upper query is right. I had an another problem with `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` which I didnt adress here.

the saved Date in DB is: '2017-09-26 02:00:00'
and tried to search for: '2017-09-26'

It didnt match on the MySQL DB so it returned all matches (from the further filter)